# Installation button using AS3.0 in Flash

Tags: pdf, button, download, installation

I havent seen this question asked here yet, which makes me wonder if its a common question at all! But hopefully someone out there knows!

I'm creating a catelog for the business I work for and the index page has to be done in Flash (I have no acess to the old program used). Basically how the CD Cat works (at least the old ones I have) you put the disc in, it auto launches, and an index pops up. On that index there are 3 links, Install, View, and Website (pluss an exit button). The Install button when pressed launches InstalShield Wizard which begins to then download the PDF files for the Cat (right now the catelog is comprised of the index page, and PDF files. If you click the 'view' button it goes to a PDF index of all the companies products.) and a link to the website.  Basically when the whole thing is done installing, there are 2 icons on the desktop: one brings you to the website and one opens a downloaded copy of the CD Cat. Just the PDF files though.

I have no idea what program was used in creating the origional catelog index, and I tried contacting the person who did it but he doesnt remember (this was several years ago and he left nothing for me to go on). I'm entirely new to Flash, only just learning, and so something like creating a download button is daunting to me. I dont even know where to begin! If anyone could spare some info or even where I could go to learn more about this, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically an autorun CD with a flash projector on it. A Flash projector is a self contained flash executable.

**Article on Autorun CD like that was made:**

http://www.webwasp.co.uk/tutorials/a24-autorun-CD/index.php

You can make a regular windows autorun pretty easily but making a hybrid that runds on mac and windows is quite a bit tougher.

In order to copy over PDFs or do system type commands you will need to use 'fscommand' which can run executables and even windows batch files.

**How to run executables is covered here:**

http://www.wuup.co.uk/as3-how-to-run-applications-from-a-flash-projector-exe-with-actionscript-3-and-batch-files

**The fscommand reference is covered here:**

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well it did answer another question I haddnt asked (about how to make the cd autorun) but isnt that just so that when the user puts the CD into the drive the cd starts? Thats not what I'm looking for with this particular question.  What I basically need to know what code I have to do, or what steps I have to go through, to make it so that when a customer puts the CD in their computer, and the screen comes up, they can click the 'install' button and a download will begin so they can have the PDF files installed on their computer. So they can view them even if they dont have the disc.

Comment: My answer has been edited to better answer your question. You would use fscommand with the 'exec' command to execute an executable or batch file which would do the pdf copying. This would only work if you use a flash projector.